# Polymer DOM-repeat content depending on received data

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have made a DOM-repeat that recieves multiple types of data.
Now I want the DOM-repeat to only show the items related to that type.
Is it possible to do this and how would I be able to achieve this?
When the item.Type is Zone I want it to display the item.Name and item.ZoneID
when the item.Type is Building I want it to display the item.BuildingID,  item.Address1 and item.Address2

This is my code:

```
 <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
          <paper-card id="departmentspaperContainer2">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3>Type: {{item.Type}}</h3>
              <hr/>
              <h4>Name:       {{item.Name}}</h4>
              <h4>BuildingID: {{item.BuildingID}}</h4>
              <h4>ZoneID:     {{item.ZoneID}}</h4>
              <h4>Address1:   {{item.Address1}}</h4>
              <h4>Address2:   {{item.Address2}}</h4>
            </div>
          </paper-card>
        </template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar to what 'HakanC' is proposing, but differently, you can use the `dom-if` and bind the response of your filter function :

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caribouflex/L0w9xzaf/1/) (to use in chrome)

```
<dom-module id="os-test">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
            <paper-card id="departmentspaperContainer2">
                <div class="cardContent" type="{{item.Type}}">
                  <h3>Type: [[item.Type]]</h3>
                  <hr/>
                  <template is='dom-if' if='{{showZone(item.Type)}}'>
                     <h4>Name: [[item.Name]]</h4>
                     <h4>ZoneID: [[item.ZoneID]]</h4>
                  </template>
                  <template is='dom-if' if='{{showBuilding(item.Type)}}'>
                     <h4>BuildingID:[[item.BuildingID]]</h4>
                     <h4>Address1: [[item.Address1]]</h4>
                     <h4>Address2: [[item.Address2]]</h4>
                  </template>
                </div>
            </paper-card>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  class OsTestElement extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() {
      return 'os-test';
    }

    static get properties() {
      return {
        data: {
          type: Array,
          value: () => {
            return [
                {
                Type:"Zone",
                Name:"valueName1",
                BuildingID:"valueBuildingID1",
                ZoneID:"valueZoneID1",
                Address1:"valueAddress11",
                Address2:"valueAddress21",
              },
              {
                Type:"Zone",
                Name:"valueName2",
                BuildingID:"valueBuildingID2",
                ZoneID:"valueZoneID2",
                Address1:"valueAddress12",
                Address2:"valueAddress22",
              },
              {
                Type:"Building",
                Name:"valueName3",
                BuildingID:"valueBuildingID3",
                ZoneID:"valueZoneID3",
                Address1:"valueAddress13",
                Address2:"valueAddress23",
              },
              {
                Type:"Building",
                Name:"valueName4",
                BuildingID:"valueBuildingID4",
                ZoneID:"valueZoneID4",
                Address1:"valueAddress14",
                Address2:"valueAddress24",
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }

    showZone(item) {
        return (item==="Zone");
    }

    showBuilding(item) {
        return (item==="Building");
    }
  }
  window.customElements.define(OsTestElement.is, OsTestElement);
</script>
```

Comment: Good example... Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You may use `dom-if` into `dom-repeat` as fallow.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
          <paper-card id="departmentspaperContainer2">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h3>Type: {{item.Type}}</h3>
              <hr/>
              <h4>Name:       {{item.Name}}</h4>

              <template is='dom-if' if='{{_show(item.Type)}}'>
                 <h4>ZoneID:     {{item.ZoneID}}</h4>
              </template>
              <template is='dom-if' if='{{!_show(item.Type)}}'>
                 <h4>BuildingID: {{item.BuildingID}}</h4>
                 <h4>Address1:   {{item.Address1}}</h4>
                 <h4>Address2:   {{item.Address2}}</h4>
               </template>
            </div>
          </paper-card>
        </template>
```

....

```
  _show(it){
       return (it === "Zone");
  }
```

With above logic should solve the problem.

Comment: After making the changes you described, the data wouldn't show up on my screen anymore. After checking it looks like the functions runs through the data but after it desides if it is true or false nothing happens.

Comment: I think it's need some small arrangement. I will test it with my side than correct it. But the logic should work